# Save bi-directional association without using cascade

Tags: hibernate

The question is it possible to save a bi-directional association in hibernate without the cascade annotation and thus avoiding transient object exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use cascade then you need to explictly save both entities.

```
entity1.setEntity(entity2)
entity2.setEntity(entity1)
session.save(entity1)
session.save(entity2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **cascade = CascadeType.ALL** for this

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "invoice")
    public class Invoice {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private int id;

        @Column(name = "invoice_date")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date invoiceDate;

        @Column(name = "customer")
        private String customer;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "itemPk.invoice", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<InvoiceItem> invoiceItems;
....

}
```

so then in your code,

```
InvoiceDao invoiceDao =  new InvoiceDao();
Invoice invoice =  new Invoice();
invoice.setInvoiceDate(new Date());
invoice.setCustomer("Sameera");

InvoiceItem invoiceItem1 =  new InvoiceItem();
invoiceItem1.setQty(10);
invoiceItem1.setPrice(100.10d);

InvoiceItemPK itemPk1 = new InvoiceItemPK();
itemPk1.setInvoice(invoice);
itemPk1.setItem(item);
invoiceItem1.setItemPk(itemPk1);

List<InvoiceItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add(invoiceItem1);
invoice.setInvoiceItems(items);
invoiceDao.save(invoice);
```